# Running a Server Side Method/Process OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC. I have defined a button in one of my views (bootstrap):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

Now, I want to execute some server side code when this button is clicked however I am not sure how to do it in an `MVC project`. Where should place the server side code and how should I call it ? I am using `Razor`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what you want to do at the function call

Comment: @PratikBhoir I will run IronPython code which will process some data and update the database. In general, I will run some code that updates the database.

Comment: MVC is not working as event driven architecture. So you should handle, post/get method manualy, with links, or forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best bet is to look at jquery/ajax in the 1st instance as there are many. many examples on SO that allude to this pattern. Below is a quick sketch to get you going.

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-success').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your url in ironpython",
            data: {datavariable:somedatatosend},
            context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
            // update any divs required here with the
            // returned json result (or text)
            $(this).addClass("done");
        });
    };
};
```

if your target url was mvc, then you'd replace the url parameter above with something like:

```
url: '@Url.Action("myAction","myController")'
```

Comment: no need to use only ajax. he need to fire a controller action method. This may be with, ajax, links or forms...

Comment: good popint ali, however, the fact that he didn't include the button wrapped in a form tag led me to conclude that he was looking for a javascript option. however, that's definmitely a way too

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. So in an event, I will basically redirect the client request to the related controller/action right ?

Comment: if you decide to go down the jquery route, you might find this little article useful: `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344292/ASP-NET-MVC-Razor-With-jQuery-For-Beginners`

Answer (score 1):

MVC stands for `model-view-controller`. We use `Controller Classes` to handle incoming browser requests. Here you can call a method in your controller using java-script.

It is better if you can follow the [MVCMovie tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) to get a clear understanding.

Thanks!