# check if button was clicked in the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following button and when clicked it's invoking a function,

Is there a way to know in the **controller** that this button was clicked ?

```
$("#RemoveFile").on("click", RemoveFile);

<button class="btn" style="height: 25px"  type="button" id="RemoveFile"><p >Remove File</p></button>
```

Comment: Controller as in server-side controller?

Comment: as in net-mvcontroller, yes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753952/running-a-server-side-method-process-onclick/24754311#comment38406319_24754311

Comment: @mplungjan-correct MVC5 project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edurado Says this the implementation which you asked to him

First set hidden field in html page (razor view/ aspx page)

```
<input type="hidden" id="StakeholderId" name="stakeholderId" />
```

Then add script like below

```
 $( "#buttonID" ).click(function() {
  $( "StakeholderId" ).val(true);
});
```

And get the value and posting the value to controller like below

```
 var hidden= $('StakeholderId').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Controller/Method",
        data: {

  hiddenField1: hidden,
  hiddenField2: "hiddenValue2",

},
        success: function() {
            alert("yay")
        },
        error: function(e) {
             console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 2):

When you click in the button, add an onclick event to this very button and save the clicked status in a hidden field. Then, whenever you send data to the controller, send this hidden field value, stating whether the button was clicked.

**UPDATED:**

Here is the HTML

```
<input id="hdnRemoveClicked" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

And here is the javascript which adds the click event in the button with `ID="RemoveFile"`, and set the hidden field value as true, to show it is clicked.

```
$( "#RemoveFile" ).click(function() {
  $( "hdnRemoveClicked" ).val(true);
  // do other things, if needed
});
```

Comment: I new to this topic can you please provide example?

Comment: If you need more help, please be give us more specific information of what you need

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to so this in MVC is to make an Ajax call to the server via an anonymous function in the JQuery component. Example:

```
$("#RemoveFile").on("click", "RemoveFile", function () {
    //  tell server
    var jqxhr1 = $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: "/myControllerUrl", 
                data: { buttonID: "RemoveFile" } });
    $.when(jqxhr1).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (textStatus != "success") {
            alert("Error, please try later");
            return false;
        }
        // update the user interface
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call to a method in Controller where a session keeps track if button was clicked.